# How to change IBM Lotus User Information Title and Company field

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, domino-designer-eclipse

I have one user list from excel.
Our all user have a generic Employe ID number on the system.
I want to compare Employe ID and if match the Employee ID, it is update the Company, title and Department information from excell list.
I need one Lotus script please help me :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you'll need to do is add a new view that is indexed by Employee ID to the Domino Directory. Let's call it "Employees by ID". Then you will need to write code that opens the Domino Directory database:

```
dim s as new NotesSession
dim myDb as new NotesDatabse("yourServer","names.nsf")
myView = myDb.GetView("Employees by ID")
```

After that, your code will read entries from the spreadsheet into variables theEmployeeId, theDepartment, and theCompany, followed by code like this:

```
dim doc as NotesDocument
doc = myView.GetDocumentByKey(theEmployeeId)
if not doc is nothing then
  doc.ReplaceItemValue("Title",theTitle)
  doc.ReplaceItemValue("Department",theDepartment)
  doc.ReplaceItemValue("CompanyName",theCompany)
  doc.Save(true,false,false)
end if
```